# Is there any way to access the second element of every tuple in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples with two elements in each tuple, like so:

```
[('cat', 'meow'), ('dog', 'bark'), ('wolf', 'bark'), ('cow', 'moo')]
```

I am searching for tuples with bark that have bark or meow in previous tuple, and print animal names:

```
cat, dog
dog, wolf
```

I know this can be done using the previous and next pointers in a C linked list, but is there any in-built method to do the same in Python?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to return the first element of every tuple where the second element is bark and the previous tuple has either bark or meow as the second element in it. Here, I am searching for the first bark (dog, bark). Now I need to traverse back to the previous tuple and see if it has either bark or meow as the second element. If yes, I print the first element of botht the tuples in the original order of the list.

Comment: @PaulRooney cat, dog will also be a result because the second element of the previous tuple = meow | bark

Comment: can't you jsut iterate over array and check i-1th element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that you need an in-built method to do that, neither is it available. You can simply scan each element of the list and get your result. Have a look at this:

```
L = [("cat", "meow"), ("dog", "bark"), ("wolf", "bark"), ("cow", "moo")]
for idx in range(1,len(L)):
    if L[idx][1] == "bark":
        if L[idx-1][1] in ["bark", "meow"]:
            print L[idx-1][0]+", "+L[idx][0]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [('cat', 'meow'), ('dog', 'bark'), ('wolf', 'bark'), ('cow', 'moo')]
filter1st = ["bark","meow"]
filter2nd = ["bark"]

for i in range(1,len(list)):
  (name1,sound1)=list[i-1]
  (name2,sound2)=list[i]
  if sound1 in filter1st and sound2 in filter2nd:
    print name1 + ", " + name2
```

Answer (score 1):

A more functional approach might be

```
inp = [('cat', 'meow'), ('dog', 'bark'), ('wolf', 'bark'), ('cow', 'moo')]

for (an1, snd1), (an2, snd2) in zip(inp, inp[1:]):
    if snd2 == 'bark' and snd1 in ('bark, meow'):
        print('%s, %s' % (an1, an2))
```

You can use `zip` on the list and a slice of the list, to iterate over it 2 elements at a time. Thats probably about as close to built in you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension for that (you need to scan the elements anyway):

```
v = [("cat", "meow"), ("dog", "bark"), ("wolf", "bark"), ("cow", "moo")]

print [ itm[0] for itm in v if itm[1] in ["bark", "meow"] ]
```